# Visualizing Kmeans cluster after application of TSNE

Tags: python, k-means, scatter-plot

```
k_model = KMeans(n_clusters = 3).fit(actor_w2vec)
cluster_dict = {i: np.where(k_model.labels_ == i)[0] for i in range(k_model.n_clusters)}
```

I have applied KMeans on word2vec vector (3411x128). cluster_dict contains the cluster label(i.e. 0,1,2) as key and index number(1,2,3,4,....3411) as value such that these values are distributed among three clusters.

Now i want to visualize these cluster so i used TSNE to reduce the 128 dimension vector to 2 dimension

```
node_embeddings = actor_w2vec
transform = TSNE #PCA

trans = transform(n_components=2)
node_embeddings_2d = trans.fit_transform(node_embeddings)
```

but i don't know how combine  these two in order to create a graph or scatter plot where all the point belonging to one cluster are combined together

Answer (score 0):

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

#remember to scale your data if the ranges are too broad 
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(df)

kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=3, max_iter=500, random_state=42)
y_km = kmeans_model.fit_predict(scaled_features)

pca_model = PCA(n_components=2, random_state=42)
transformed = pca_model.fit_transform(scaled_features)
centers = pca_model.transform(kmeans_model.cluster_centers_)

fig = px.scatter(x=transformed[:, 0], y=transformed[:, 1], color=y_km)
fig.add_scatter(
    x=centers[:, 0],
    y=centers[:, 1],
    marker=dict(size=20, color="LightSeaGreen"), name="Centers"
)
fig.show()
```

If you only do `kmeans.fit(df)`, you could get the labels from `kmeans.labels_`

Answer (score -1):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150 
# create dataset
X, y = make_blobs(
   n_samples=150, n_features=2,
   centers=3, cluster_std=0.5,
   shuffle=True, random_state=0
)
# plot
plt.scatter(
   X[:, 0], X[:, 1],
   edgecolor='black', s=50
)
plt.show()
km = KMeans(
        n_clusters=3, init='random',
        n_init=10, max_iter=10000, 
        tol=1e-04, random_state=0
    )
y_km = km.fit_predict(X)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=y_km, s=50, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, alpha=0.4)
plt.scatter(km.cluster_centers_[:, 0],km.cluster_centers_[:, 1], 
        s=250, marker='*', label='centroids',
        edgecolor='black',
       c=np.arange(0,3),cmap=plt.cm.Paired,)
```

[image]

[image]

The line `import seaborn as sns; sns.set()` is not necessary, it just makes a nicer style.

For plotting you can use `matplotlib.pyplot` . Furthermore you can look on the shape of your data with node_embeddings_2d.shape, so you can make sure that  `plt.scatter` takes the right arguments.
Good luck! ;)